# postfix: send a copy of every email to a given email address

Tags: email, smtp, postfix-mta

I have a postfix email server and there is an issue I want to debug.
How can I configure it to send a copy of every email to my email (in addition to delivering the email to its intended recipients).

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/407302/how-can-i-configure-postfix-to-retain-copies-of-all-email-sent-through-it has much better answer as it uses features provided by postfix.

Answer (score 13):

Just add `always_bcc=youremail@gmail.com` in /etc/postfix/main.cf and restart postfix server. I've added this line in the bottom.

It really seems to be working. More about always_bcc [here](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html)

Please don't forget to backup this file first.

Comment: Works like a charm. This should be the accepted answer!

Comment: Agree - best answer

Answer (score 10):

I recently got this working, so though I'd share:

Sending all outgoing mail into Sent folders with postfix and cyrus imap.

Summary

Make postfix send bcc copies of all outgoing emails to a special "sent"
mail account.  Use sieve on this special account to redirect all emails
to the Sent folder associated with the account.

1. Create the email user account for sent

   The easiest way to do this is to create a new unix account for sent,
   setting the shell to /bin/false to prevent anyone from being able to log
   in:

   ```
   host$ sudo useradd sent
   host$ sudo chsh -s /bin/false sent
   ```
2. Set up imap for the sent user

   Using cyradm we create a new mailbox (ie user) and give that user append
   access to all of our imap "Sent" folders:

   ```
   host$ $ cyradm -user cyrus localhost
   Password: <enter you cyrus user admin password here>
   localhost> createmailbox user.sent
   localhost> setaclmailbox user.%.Sent sent append
   Setting ACL on user.userx.Sent...OK.
   Setting ACL on user.usery.Sent...OK.
   . . .
   Setting ACL on user.userz.Sent...OK.
   localhost> exit
   ```
3. Create a sieve script for the sent account

   This script will redirect all incoming email to the sent account, to the
   Sent folder in the senders Inbox.

   My script is called sent.sieve and looks something like this:

   ```
    # Sieve script for sent.  If outgoing email is bcc'ed to this account,
    # this sieve script will redirect it to the sender's Sent folder
    require ["fileinto"];

    if address :is :localpart "From" "userx" {
      fileinto "user.userx.Sent";
    }
    elsif address :is :localpart "From" "usery" {
      fileinto "user.usery.Sent";
    }
    elsif address :is :localpart "From" "userz" {
      fileinto "user.userz.Sent";
   }
   ```

   You will need to put in an entry for each of your users (userx, usery,
   userz in the example above).  I have not been able to
   find a better way of doing this.  Suggestions are welcomed to
   marc@bloodnok.com

   Install the sieve script like this:

   ```
   host$ sieveshell localhost -user=sent -a=cyrus
   Password: <enter you cyrus user admin password here>
   > put sent.sieve
   > activate sent.sieve
   > quit
   ```
4. Set up the bcc mapping for postfix

   In the postfix directory (/etc/postfix on debian) create a file called
   bcc_map that looks like this:

   ```
   # copy all locally sent mail to the sent account
   @yourdomain.com       sent@yourdomain.com
   ```

   Compile this into a postfix hash file using:

   ```
   host$ sudo postmap bcc_map
   ```

   Add the following line to the postfix main.cf configuration file:

   ```
   sender_bcc_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/bcc_map
   ```

   And make postfix reload its configuration:

   host$ sudo /etc/init.d/postfix reload
5. Test and Debug

   Send some email and check that it is copied into your Sent folder.

   In the event of problems you should check the cyrus and postfix logs
   (all logged to `/var/log/syslog` on my debian host).  Typos and incorrect
   access permissions will usually result in some clue being sent to the
   logs.